# Is there a specific tex for book translation?

Tags: books

I am translating a book. The PDF is generated with mirrored gray letters. I think the problem is in the `cls` (which I don't have) or `aux`, as it is preset there. How to solve this? Better to work with another TeX?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}

\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{textcomp}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}

\graphicspath{{./Figuras/}}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%FAZ EDICOES AQUI (somente no conteudo que esta entre entre as ultimas  chaves de cada linha!!!)

\newcommand{\partedolivro}{\textbf{1} Descrição física de uma máquina}

\newcommand{\titulo}{Máquina}

\newcommand{\autorum}{Carlos Augusto}

\newcommand{\autordois}{}

\newcommand{\volume}{Único}

\newcommand{\numero}{1}

\newcommand{\ano}{1980}

\newcommand{\pagina}{1 - 5}

%ATE AQUI !!!

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l p{12cm} l l}


        \toprule[0.8 mm]
        \textbf{Título} &                   &                       &               \\
        \hline
                        &|  \partedolivro   &                       &               \\ 
                        &|                  &                       &               \\
        \hline

        \textbf{Autores}&                   &                       &               \\
        \hline
                        &|  \autorum        &                       &               \\
                        &|  \autordois      &                       &               \\
        \hline      

        \textbf{Livro}   &| \titulo         &                       &               \\
        \hline

        \textbf{Volume}  &|   \volume       &   | \textbf{Número}   &  | \numero    \\
        \hline

        \textbf{Ano}     &|  \ano           &   | \textbf{Páginas}  & | \pagina         \\

    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{12pt}



\section{Resumo} 

  \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If someone can do something useful with the information given here, they have all my admiration.

Comment: What @frougon tries to say with his comment is, that we need *much* more information to help you. Can you please show us some minimal example of code which produces your "mirrored gray letters". That example must contain `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and the code that is necessary to reproduce your issue. We don't magically know what you did or are doing, you have to show us.

Comment: How can the problem be in a file you don't have access to?

Comment: I see no problem with your revised MWE, certainly no mirrored letters.

Comment: @PeterWilson Seriously, the letters are grayer than black, as are the other PDFs I have here?

Comment: Try another pdf reader?

Comment: If you think your PDF looks worse compared to other PDFs, consider including a screenshot of what it looks like, along with a screenshot of some other PDF that you think looks fine (taken on the same computer at the same zoom/resolution, preferably another PDF also generated with LaTeX and using the same font). (Also mention the operating system and PDF viewer used.)

Comment: @rsa The sectional titles are in a bold (extra black) font. If you want everytihng in bold than that is up to you but I don't advise it.

Comment: @PeterWilson No, not that. I want the body of the text to be blacker than it appears. The normal.

Comment: I want to thank all the collaborators above. I started to find other problems with this template and decided to abandon it. I started studying the memoir class and I liked it. I will do a test there. The difficult thing is that I will have to start from scratch.

Comment: @PeterWilson I will need you a lot. But in advance, thank you very much.

Comment: @rsa, you just found out that you don't like Computer Modern, perhaps because you're too used to word processors, whose fonts really look better on screen. Look for another font.

Comment: @Joseph, understand.